# Java program only to detect a computer in LAN is connected to internet or not

Tags: java

I am making a server and connecting two clients in java though LAN. Now, I want to detect if any of the client is connected to internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. There are several possible questions here.  (1) Can the client detect whether it is itself capable of connecting to the Internet (2) Can the client tell if it has an open connection to the Internet (3) Can the _server_ detect if a client is capable of connecting to the Internet (4) Can the _server_ detect if a client currently has an active connection to the Internet.... which is it?

Comment: (4) Can the server detect if a client currently has an active connection to the internet... That's what I want.

Comment: I've been given a mini project that is for secretly detecting the online activities of their children. Also any help regarding this, is highly appreciated. Thanks